# Bibliography bib won't work

Tags: bibtex

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper] {article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage [Symbol]{upgreek}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{apacite}
\author{Bibliography}
\date{18 oktober 2019}
\title{Learn to work with LaTeX}


\begin{document}

pagenumbering{gobble}
\maketitle

\newpage

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\newpage

\bibliography{bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\cite{cameron_1999}
\cite{cohen_hachenberger_2000}


\end{document}
```

I have created a separate bib file for the sources. But I only get the result that looks like this. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I have followed instructions that I found on youtube. Still, my sources won't look normal.

Why are there not any spaces between the sources, and what does (0, ) mean?

[image]

Result when I removed the apacite package

[image]

Comment: Please make the example self contained. We do not know that is in the `bibliography.bib` file. Also what happens if you remove the `apacite` package and reruns latex+bibtex+latex+latex

Comment: It worked when I removed apacite. I don't understand what self contained mean, please explain further. Should it look like this when making sources? Is it normal to have [1][2] down on page?

Comment: Self contained means that what  you have posted is what is needed to compile the document (given a full latex installation). Here it is not slef contained as it refers to a bib file we do not have access to,  thus we cannot test your mwe as we don't have all the files needed. Numbers are the default yes. If you want author-year style, have a look at the natbib package and the bibliography styles compatible with it (plain is not one of them, but plainnat is)

Comment: `\usepackage{apacite}` is not compatible with `\bibliographystyle{plain}`. If you load the `apacite` package you need to say `\bibliographystyle{apacite}`. Note that `apacite` will give you a citation and bibliography style according to the APA manual (6th ed.), this is a very specific style used in psychology and related fields, but it has some interesting properties, so it might not be what you are looking for if you just want a simple author-year style. If you don't want APA style, remove `\usepackage{apacite}`.

Comment: The output shown in the second screenshot (the one where you removed `\usepackage{apacite}`) looks perfectly normal and is exactly what I would expect from the code you show. You have `\cite{cameron_1999}` and `\cite{cohen_hachenberger_2000}` and those two commands print [1] and [2] after the bibliography: Usually one would probably not cite stuff like this after the bibliography, but one would instead use the commands in the normal flow of text. If you want author-year citations (Cameron 1999) you need to choose a different style and load a package.